# calling function as a lambda inside a dict seems to change its output

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I'm noticing that I get unexpected results when I call functions as lambdas in a dict.

The application is price-sensitivity estimation (i.e., the change in each segment's demand as a result of a change in price):

```
segments = ['A','B','C']  # price segments

p  = {'A':  200, 'B':  200, 'C':  200}  # baseline price
d  = {'A':  150, 'B':  100, 'C':   70}  # baseline demand
e  = {'A': -0.4, 'B': -0.5, 'C': -0.8}  # elasticity estimate

print( d['A'] * ( 1 + e['A']*(100 - p['A'])/p['A'] ) ) # 180, as expected
print( d['B'] * ( 1 + e['B']*(200 - p['B'])/p['B'] ) ) # 100, as expected
print( d['C'] * ( 1 + e['C']*(300 - p['C'])/p['C'] ) ) #  42, as expected
```

For reusability, I'd like to store the demand function for each segment as a lambda, in a dict keyed to the segment name. My attempt:

```
demand  = { s: lambda x: d[s] * ( 1 + e[s]*(x - p[s])/p[s] )
              for s in segments
          }
```

But calling these lambdas gives different results from the previous calculations:

```
print(demand['A'](100)) # 98, expected 180
print(demand['B'](200)) # 70, expected 100
print(demand['C'](300)) # 42, as expected
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think this is essentially the same problem as: [What do lambda function closures capture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture)

Comment: Thanks @Mark, that link put me on to this: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result